# Why does HandlerThread have a run() method, and how should I use it?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handlerthread

I developed several codes using HandlerThread, but so far, it is to some extent difficult to grasp the meaning of the `run()` method that exists in the `Handlerthread` class when extended.

`HandlerThread` class, when extended, some abstract methods are to be overridden. One of them is:

```
run()
```

Would you please clarify the usage of it in the `HandlerThread` class?

Comment: I'm not an android developer, and I can't answer, but is it possible that what you _really_ are asking here is, "what is the purpose of the `HandlerThread` class?" I looked at its documentation, and I couldn't figure out what it's for (i.e., I couldn't see who calls it, or when, or why) but it sure looks as of the entire point of that class is to call that `run()` method at the right time (or probably, times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HandlerThread` is a subclass of `Thread`, and `Thread` has a [`run()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#run()).

HandlerThread [overrides that](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/0e33abbe39b068cf2aed5f3db50b855fb8e6121c:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java;l=58) in order to do its work, because that's how Threads are implemented.  Unfortunately, it doesn't replace the JavaDoc comment with its own, so the documentation is copied from the `Thread` class, which results in confusing documentation here.

As far as how you should use it: you shouldn't.  It's an implementation detail that is, unfortunately, public.  You shouldn't override it or call it.  Just [get the `Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread#getLooper()) and use that to post things to the `HanderThread`.